# Downscaling JPG during JPG decompression

Tags: c++, math, jpeg, compression

I have to downscale and decompress a set of JPG images of size 4608 x 3456.  Currently, I have already been able to decompress the images correctly to RGB format and convert them to a Bitmap.

Now I need to implement the downscale, and from what I've read so far to downscale an image correctly one should use Bilinear Interpolation.  Then I should replace the pixels (2x2) that were used for the interpolation by the resulted pixel from the interpolation.  I need the about at about 1/4 of its current size.

I'm not so worried about the quality of the downscaled images, as I am about the speed at which it is done.  The whole process should be as fast as it can be.

My question is, *when* I should do the bilinear interpolation during the decompression stage of the JPG.  Should I do it after the IDCT (Inverse Discrete Cosine Transform) or should I perform the interpolation before the IDCT?

Is it smart to use the DCT coefficents and do the interpolation on them and then use those resulted values to in the IDCT?

Comment: Who said you should use bilinear? That's the worst possible way apart from point sampling. Also it's important to pay attention to correctly handle gamma.

Comment: @AxelGneiting That was merely what I've found from my research, if you can suggest a better way, please do so.

Comment: @AxelGneiting, in this particular application bilinear will be mathematically equivalent to taking an average of all 4 pixels. That should be very fast and acceptable quality. It's possible to get higher quality at the expense of speed. Same for handling gamma - better results, less speed.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I don't believe there's any sensible way that you can do this in terms of the DCT coefficients.

However, if you specifically want an image of half the size in each dimension, you could get a crudely downsampled image by throwing away the high-frequency coefficients and doing a 4x4 IDCT.

Comment: It's not such a ridiculous idea - I've worked with a library that used this approach for generating thumbnails. Unfortunately I never learned the details of how it operated.

Comment: @Oli can you give me a bit more data on how this would be done?

Comment: @Tony: Each 8x8 block of the image has a 2D DCT applied to it (I'm sure you already know this).  Each coefficient represents the amplitude of a particular 2D spatial frequency.  You want to downsample, which basically involves filtering away the high frequencies first (this is what the interpolation is doing).  You would get a similar effect by setting the high-frequency coeffs to 0.  Alternatively, you could just ignore them, and retain only the low-freq 4x4 coeffs from each block, and perform a 4x4 IDCT on them (see the Wikipedia page on DCT for the maths).

Comment: So I basically have to get the high frequencies in each 8x8 block of the image and set them to zero.  How would I know what are the high frequencies in each block?  After that, I can just apply the IDCT to the remaining frequencies, right?

Comment: @Tony: You don't need to explicitly set them to zero; just ignore them.  Then apply the transform to the low 4x4.  The low-frequency coeffs are the ones "closest" to the DC coeff; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_codec_example.