# Remove high-frequency coefficients from JPG image

Tags: c++, compression, jpeg

Based on this [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656747/downscaling-jpg-during-jpg-decompression) answer, I need to remove the high-frequency DCT coefficients from my image during decompression to get a smaller image.

I've been searching for a way to do this, and it seems it's not that simple.  I have the following two loops that do the IDCT in my code, and doing the loops over a subset of the 8 x 8 blocks, only gives very distorted images.

```
 for (coef = 0;  coef < 64;  coef +=8)
        njRowIDCT(&nj.block[coef]); //Inverse Discrete Cosine Transform
    for (coef = 0;  coef < 8;  ++coef)
        njColIDCT(&nj.block[coef], &out[coef], c->stride);  // Inverse Discrete Cosine Transform
```

`block` is an array of 64 `int`'s

I know that the coefficients I need to remove are in the lower right corner of each block, however what would be the best method of removing or discarding them properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think, simply discarding high frequency components won't work. Your observation also proves that. Because, when you average 2x2 or 4x4 block, you won't completely discard a certain high frequency component. Instead, you decrease their energy level respect to low frequencies. So, decreasing completely to zero is not good idea.

I think, you didn't pay attention enough what high frequency really means. Please apply a Sobel or Prewitt edge detection to your image and binarize it. Then query each pixel on that binary image that whether it's a part of edge or discarded. If it's a part of edge, then apply an average filter on your original image by "excluding" current pixel. Now, guess what it looks like?

Comment: And this will downscale my image?

Comment: Obviously not. It was an example for you to understand what high frequency removing means. Just imagine my example. You don't need to implement. If you think it properly, you will understand that high frequency elimination is not feasible solution.

Comment: I get it now, so do you have an answer on how to downscale my image then?

Comment: I think, to downsample an image with averaging of frequency is simply won't work. Because, working on frequency domain is not same as time domain (i.e. actual pixels). So, I'm out of options. But, at least you can measure downsampling performance at YCbCr planes. Since, most of JPEG images already have downsampled CbCr planes, it could be fast enough (you've less data to process).